# What is the output of this PYTHON range statement and WHY?

Tags: python, range

The code is written below :

```
print(list(range(0,-5)))
```

I cannot understand how it produces an empty list ?

Comment: Did you mean `print(list(range(0,-5, -1)))`?

Answer (score 2):

The range is trying to go from 0 to -5 by adding but you can't do that so it just returns an empty list.
*(i think)*

Use `range(0, -5, -1)` to go backwards by one.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple.

If you provide a **number** `n` as argument for **range(0, n)**, then the method by standard will return all numbers between 0 and n (starting from 0). Since there are no such numbers when `n` **is negative**, the result is an **empty list** `[]`.

Still it provides the possibility to define a **custom value** to step through between the 2 **given numbers**, by passing an optional third argument like so:

```
print(list(range(0, -5, -1))) # '[0, -1, -2, -3, -4]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the python **`range()`** function has 3 arguments:

> start,stop,step.

You are getting an empty list, because you are asking your python range function to start from 0 and go back to -5, which is a wrong way to approach, as the *function expects to go on the right side of the scale every step.*
So, if you try something like:

```
print(list(range(-5,0)) -> [-5,-4,-3,-2,-1]
```

Give this a read: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp

Answer (score 0):

range is in-built function in Python which returns a sequence of numbers start to stop-1
range(start, stop, step)
list(range(0,-5))
start=0
stop=-5
it will compare start and stop that is: 0<-5, it will return false
so your output is empty list